# Reading Information from a textbox in VBA in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I just found out about VBA yesterday and I am having fun playing with it, however I encountered a problem: how do you read the contents of a textbox.  Its the only textbox on the slide and I want it to be able to apply to all slides in the PowerPoint.  Please ask me to clarify if that does not make sense.

--EDIT--
Basically, I want to read contents of a text box, simple as that.

--EDIT--
Here is my current code:

```
Sub answer()
    Dim lCurrentView As Long
    Dim myInput As String
    Dim sld As Slide
    Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
    myInput = sld.Shapes(4).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    A = InputBox(prompt:="Your Answer:")
    MsgBox (myInput)
    If A = myInput Then
        MsgBox ("Correct!")
        ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow _
        .View.GotoSlide Int(Rnd * _
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Count) + 1
    Else
        MsgBox ("Sorry, try again...")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to run this macro and check the result in the Debug window (press Ctrl+G to open it). Execute it step by step (pressing F8) and put some breakpoints (pressing F9) and check the object browser (select one variable and press Shift+F2)

```
Sub Test()
  Dim Sld As Slide, Shp As Shape
  For Each Sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each Shp In Sld.Shapes
      Select Case Shp.Type
        Case MsoShapeType.msoTextBox
          Debug.Print Sld.Name, Shp.Name, Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        Case Else
          Debug.Print Sld.Name, Shp.Name, "This is not a text box"
      End Select
    Next Shp
  Next Sld
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Type some text in the first textbox on the first slide of your presentation.  Then open the VBA editor, right click under "VBAProject", and select "Add Module".  In the new module, paste the following code and press the "play" button.

```
Sub Textbox_reader()
    Dim myInput As String
    myInput = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    MsgBox (myInput)
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the simple answer, but my question is now: how do you find the textbox content on the current slide. (See my edit for my current code)

Comment: Assuming you have only 1 textbox on the slide, you would replace the 4 in `Shapes(4)` with 1.  This number refers to the indexing of shapes on your slide.